how to remove for ToMany
func initObjectBox() *objectbox.ObjectBox {
    objectBox, err := objectbox.NewBuilder().Model(model.ObjectBoxModel()).Directory("./opt").Build()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return nil
    }
    return objectBox
}
func main() {
    // load objectbox
    ob := initObjectBox()
    defer ob.Close() // In a server app, you would just keep ob and close on shutdown
    box := model.BoxForTask(ob)
    box2 := model.BoxForWorkers(ob)
    if box == nil || box2 == nil {
        panic("box ini fail")
    }

    worker1 := model.Workers{Name: "Petter", Age: 18}
    worker2 := model.Workers{Name: "Leven", Age: 28}
    workers := []*model.Workers{&worker1, &worker2}
    id, _ := box.Put(&model.Task{
        Text:    "Buy milk",
        Workers: workers,
    }) //create data
    tasks, _ := box.Get(id) // Read
    box.RemoveId(id)        //remove data， but why the workers not be removed ?

    for _, t := range tasks.Workers {
        cont, err := box2.Contains(t.Id) // verify if work has been deleted
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
        }
        if cont {
            fmt.Printf("%s has not been deleted.\n", t.Name)
        } else {
            fmt.Printf("%s has been deleted.", t.Name)
        }
    }

}

The console output:
Petter has not been deleted.
Leven has not been deleted.
how to remove for ToMany?
I have run box.RemoveId(id), but why the workers not be removed??

box.RemoveId(id) only removes the Task Object from its Box and dissolves the relation to the two Workers.
To delete the Workers, they need to be removed from their Box as well. E.g. workerBox.RemoveId(workerId1).
Note: when an Object that contains a ToMany is put, only for convenience ObjectBox will also put new objects in the ToMany.

Thank you for your reply! As far as I know, this is the only way to do it.
